# Python how to get a list of (word, tag) tuples from StanfordCoreNLP subtree?

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, subtree

Python how to get a list of (word, tag) tuples from StanfordCoreNLP subtree?

like: [('they', 'PRP'), ('still', 'RB'), ('work', 'VBP'), ('in', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('factory', 'NN')].

Thanks in advance.

It was found that tree.leaves() just give a list of word, like:

def test():

```
from nltk import Tree

s = '(ROOT (S (NP (PRP I)) (VP (VBP want) (S (VP (TO to) (VP (VB know) (SBAR (IN whether) (S (NP (PRP they)) (ADVP (RB still)) (VP (VBP work) (PP (IN in) (NP (DT the) (NN factory)))))))))) (. .)))'

tree = Tree.fromstring(s)

print('Output：', tree.leaves())
```

#Output：['I', 'want', 'to', 'know', 'whether', 'they', 'still', 'work', 'in', 'the', 'factory', '.']

Comment: This is very difficult to parse, most especially because you have not block formatted your code. Please read through the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article and edit your question appropriately. The best questions on SO detail your research effort, ask a specific question, and feature a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates what you've tried and helps others see where you might have gone wrong.

Comment: Sorry the wrong layout, I had tied to edit it on-line immediately, but, it seems not take effective. Now, I re-paste it again:

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) will help. Putting all of your code in a single line in plain text is very difficult to read, not to mention syntactically invalid for a language like python. You need to consider the work you are asking the community to do in order to help you versus the work you've put in to ask a good question. If you've gone to the trouble of including properly-formatted code without extraneous detail, you'll get a much better response.